# After an upgrade to El Capitan, TexShop does not even open a window

Tags: errors, editors, texshop, macos

I am aware (sort of) of problems with path change after an upgrade. However my problem seems worse - TexShop does not give me a window after I click on the TexShop icon. It only says: TexShop cannot be opened because of a problem.
Please help. 12 July, 2017.

Comment: Have you tried simply deleting the TeXShop app and installing the latest version?

Comment: How old is your TeXShop? PS: how old is your TeX distribution? Finally, what was your previous OS version?

Comment: Thank you both for reaction. To Alan: yes I did and no change.

Comment: To Alan: I klicked mactex2017 installer again - no change.

Comment: @Herb I just downloaded mactex2017 installer and used this. I upgraded from Maveric, not sure though.

Comment: As a first try remove the TeXShop folder from ~/Library. Note: ~/Library is the Library folder in you HOME folder, NOT /Library which is at the root of your HD.

Comment: I uninstalled/evicted everything related to tex as instructed by TexUserGgroup, installed tex2017 and all seems to work. Thanks, J.

Comment: @Jacek : did you also remove all traces of TeXShop? Dick Koch told me that the problem comes up if there is more than one version of TeXShop on the system an one is rather old. Please update to the latest version of TeXShop (TeXShop->Check for Updates...) and use a TeX Live Utility to update your TeX Live Distribution (installed by MacTeX).

Comment: @Herb : yes, I removed all traces of TexShop. Indeed  when the trouble occured, I had two versions of TexShop: 2013 which I was using up to date and the newly "installed" 2017. So Dick Is correct.

Comment: @Herb : Second, yes I updated the TexShop once it kicked off and did the same with Tex Live Utility, although I never used the latter one?